# How to make ascending sublists in a list of integers go in descending order?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Working on some example questions, the particular one asks to make a function which would take a list and return a new one which would make every ascending sublist in the list go in descending order and leave the descending sublists as they are. For example, given the list `[1,2,3,4,5]`, I need the list `[5,4,3,2,1]` or given a list like `[1,2,3,5,4,6,7,9,8]` would return `[5,3,2,1,9,7,6,4,8]`

Here's what I have so far, but it does not do anything close to what I'd like it to do:

```
def example3(items):
    sublst = list()


    for i in items:

        current_element = [i]

        next_element = [i+1]

        if next_element > current_element:
            sublst = items.reverse()

        else:
            return items
    return sublst

print (example3([1,2,3,2])) #[[1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 2]]
```

EDIT:
I feel like people are a little confused as to what I want to do in this case, heres a better example of what I'd like my function to do. Given a list like: `[5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]` I would like it to return `[10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]`. As you can see all the sublists that are in descending order such as (`[5,7,10]`) gets reversed to `[10, 7, 5]`.

Comment: The example 1...9 doesn't make sense to me. Why is the first ascending sublist `[1,2,3]` instead of `[1,2,3,5]`?

Comment: @JeremyFisher woops, did not read that through that properly. [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3] would be a better example, I would like it to return [10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]

Comment: There's a lot going on here that causes problems. Misunderstanding: calling the reverse method on a list reverses it in place, you expect it to be returned. If you want sublst to be the result of reversing something, use slicing: `sublst = something[::-1]`.  The problems in this snippet are deeper: you don't really collect a sublist, you're doing odd things with how you decide elements out of order, etc.  Advice: do this in much smaller chunks and build up to the solution! It will leave you less confused.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit challenging to figure out what you need.
I think you want something like as follows:

```
import random

l = [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]
bl =[]

while True:
    if len(l) == 0:
        break
    r = random.randint(0, len(l))
    bl.extend(l[r:None:-1])
    l = l[r+1:]

print(bl)
```

**Out1:**

```
[10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
```

**Out2:**

```
[10, 7, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 3]
```

**Out3:**

```
[3, 1, 8, 7, 2, 4, 10, 7, 5]
```

**Out4:**

```
[2, 4, 10, 7, 5, 3, 1, 8, 7]
```

etc.

If you want a specific reverse random list:

```
import random

loop_number = 0
while True:
    l = [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]
    bl =[]
    while True:
        if len(l) == 0:
            break
        r = random.randint(0, len(l))
        bl.extend(l[r:None:-1])
        l = l[r+1:]
    loop_number += 1
    if bl == [10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]:
        print(bl)
        print("I tried {} times".format(loop_number))
        break
```

**Out:**

```
[10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1]
I tried 336 times
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but this wouls be a better example for what I am looking for, given the list: [5, 7, 10, 4, 2, 7, 8, 1, 3]. I would like it to return [10, 7, 5, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1].

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I don't want touch the sublists that are already in descending order. It's just the sublists that are in ascending order which need to be reversed. The first output is the closest outcome to what I would like to have.

Comment: @farhan I updated the result list, but you can get a lot of combination, now I placed the one you need in the first place.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, can you clarify how I can get just the first outcome to print? I don't need to use random.randint.

Comment: @farhan You need use random. I make addition to get your exact result from n-th try. See my update

Comment: @farhan you either need to use random, or you have to give the sublist's first member.

Comment: ah okay, but the issue now is that I have to put in my desired/predicted outcome at the "bl" spot. Is there any way to get my desired outcome without having to put it in? I want the function to work so that the list of numbers that need their sublists to be reversed could be put in by the user without touching the inside of the function.

Comment: @farhan this is another question already. Please accept my answer, create a new question regarding the new topic and I answer to it happily.

Comment: @farhan anyway you can get input with `input()`

Comment: @Geeeocode This solution basically randomizes the list until you reach the desired output. This isn't sufficient because a) you don't know the desired output on an unknown input list and b) the algorithm runtime is O(n!).

Comment: @JeremyFisher No, it only randomly choose the sublists' first element as it is not determined by OP. So we need somehow chose them.

Answer (score 0):

The general algorithm is to keep track of the current ascending sublist you are processing using 2 pointers, perhaps a "start" and "curr" pointer. `curr` iterates over each element of the list. As long as the current element is greater than the previous element, you have an ascending sublist, and you move `curr` to the next number. If the `curr` number is less than the previous number, you know your ascending sublist has ended, so you collect all numbers from `start` to `curr - 1` (because `array[curr]` is less than `array[curr - 1]` so it can't be part of the ascending sublist) and reverse them. You then set `start = curr` before incrementing `curr`.

You will have to deal with the details of the most efficient way of reversing them, as well as the edge cases with the pointers like what should the initial value of `start` be, as well as how to deal with the case that the current ascending sublist extends past the end of the array. But the above paragraph should be sufficient in getting you to think in the right direction.